# My footer in html is displaying text in center in browser. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

whenever I try to add text in footer it already gets positioned in center. I don't know how to fix coz I can't find where is the error. Can anyone help me fix this and also whenever I try to add bootstrap link to my header it affects my drop down css also.
also Im using notepad++ for website
**html code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE.HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        E-Commerce Website
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assignment1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assi1.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
     
    
   
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
<div class="topnav-right">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Cart 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#Best Sellers">Your Orders</a>
      <a href="file:///D:/Notepad++/practials/assignment1/signup/cart.html">Proceed to checkout</a>
      
     </div>
    
</div>
</div>
<a href="file:///D:/Notepad++/practials/assignment1/Assignment1.html#home" class="active"><button class="button"  style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Home</span></button></a></span></button>
  <a href="#news"><button class="button"  style="vertical-align:middle"><span>News</span></button></a>
  <a href="file:///D:/Notepad++/practials/assignment1/signup/s1.html"><button class="button"  style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Sign Up</span></button></a>
  
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">More 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#Best Sellers">Best Sellers</a>
      <a href="#Mobiles">Smartphones</a>
      <a href="#laptops">Laptops & Desktops</a>
      <a href="#Electronics">Electronics</a>
      <a href="#Fashion">Fashion</a>
      <a href="#Furiniture">Furniture</a>
     </div>
    
</div>
<div class="srch">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</div>

</div>
</br></br>
<center><img src="banner2.jpg" width="80%" height="65%"></center>


<!--image slider-->
<br><br>

<div class="table1">
<table class="a">
<tr><td colspan="5"><h2>SmartPhones<h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<th><img src="small banner.png" width=250px></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="phone 1.png" width="70%"></a></th>
<th><img src="phone 7.jpeg" width="30%"></th>
<th><img src="phone 4.png" width="45%" ></th>
<th><img src="phone 8.png" width="60%"></th>
<th><img src="phone 6.png" width="70%"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h3>OnePlus Nord 2 5G</h3></td>
<td><h3>Poco M3 5G</h3></td>
<td><h3>Apple iPhone 12 Pro (128GB)</h3></td>
<td><h3>OnePlus 2 Pro</h3></td>
<td><h3>OnePlus 9 Pro 5G</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h4>From ₹29,999</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹29,999</h4></td>
<td><h4> ₹1,28,900</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹37,999</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹37,999</h4></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="table3">
<table class="b">
<tr><td colspan="5"><h2>Laptops<h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<th><img src="small banner.png" width=250px></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="l1.png" width="80%"></a></th>
<th><img src="l2.png" width="95%"></th>
<th><img src="L3.png" width="80%" ></th>
<th><img src="l4.png" width="80%"></th>
<th><img src="l5.png" width="80%"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h3>ROG Strix G17 Advantage Edition G713
</h3></td>
<td><h3>ROG Strix SCAR 17 G733</h3></td>
<td><h3>Razer Blade 15</h3></td>
<td><h3>Legion Y540 - Raven Black</h3></td>
<td><h3>ThinkPad E14 35.56cms-Black</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h4>₹97,999</h4></td>
<td><h4>₹1,29,999</h4></td>
<td><h4> ₹1,30,900</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹69,000</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹49,999</h4></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<center> <th><img src="banner9.jpg" width="100%" height="80%" ></th> <center>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="table3">
<table class="b">
<tr><td colspan="5"><h2>Laptops<h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<th><img src="small banner.png" width=250px></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="l1.png" width="80%"></a></th>
<th><img src="l2.png" width="95%"></th>
<th><img src="L3.png" width="80%" ></th>
<th><img src="l4.png" width="80%"></th>
<th><img src="l5.png" width="80%"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h3>ROG Strix G17 Advantage Edition G713
</h3></td>
<td><h3>ROG Strix SCAR 17 G733</h3></td>
<td><h3>Razer Blade 15</h3></td>
<td><h3>Legion Y540 - Raven Black</h3></td>
<td><h3>ThinkPad E14 35.56cms-Black</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><h4>₹97,999</h4></td>
<td><h4>₹1,29,999</h4></td>
<td><h4> ₹1,30,900</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹69,000</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹49,999</h4></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="table2">
<table class="b">
<tr><td colspan="5"><h2>Devices and accessories<h2></td></tr>
<tr>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="a1.jpeg" width="55%"></a></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="a2.jpeg" width="55%"></a></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="a3.jpeg" width="40%"></a></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="a4.jpeg" width="50%"></a></th>
<th><a href="#phone1"><img src="a5.jpeg" width="50%"></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Wired earphones</h3></td>
<td><h3>Bluetooth Headphones</h3></td>
<td><h3>Data cards</h3></td>
<td><h3>Tv streaming devices</h3></td>
<td><h3>Webcams</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>From ₹399</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹899</h4></td>
<td><h4> Upto 60% off</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹2799</h4></td>
<td><h4>From ₹490</h4></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<center><table class="brandtable">


<tr><td><img src = "logo-paypal.png"></td>
<td><img src = "logo-godrej.png"></td>
<td><img src = "logo-oppo.png"></td>
<td><img src = "logo-coca-cola.png"></td>
<td><img src = "logo-philips.png"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</center>

  <footer>
  <p> hello </p>
  </footer>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**css code**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #43cea2, #185a9d);
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
 background: orange linear-gradient(#F7971E,#FFD200);
 
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: orange linear-gradient(#FFD200);
}
.dropdown {
  padding-top:15px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ff8c00;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: center;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  width:30%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

.table a{
     table-layout: auto;

     
}
 .table a, h2{
      color: #ff4411;
      font-size: 25px; 
      font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .table a, h3{
     font-family:Roman-55,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 19px;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .table a, h4{
     font-size: 16px;
     color: #388e3c;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
 }
 .table1 {
     background-image: linear-gradient(#FFAFBD , #ffc3a0);
     background-color: white;
    
 }
 
 .table1 td, th {
            border: 0px;
            width: 200px;
 }
 .table1{
     border-radius: 25px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 10px;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  margin: 0;
 }
 
 .table2{
     border-radius: 25px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 10px;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .table2 {
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(#FFAFBD , #ffc3a0); */
     background-color: white;
    
 }
 
 .table2 td, th {
            border: 0px;
            width: 300px;
 }
 
 
 .table3{
     border-radius: 25px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 10px;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  margin: 0;
   background-image: linear-gradient(#3eadcf, #abe9cd);
    background-color: white;
 }
 
 .table3 td, th {
     border: 0px;
            width: 300px;
 }
 
/* button hover */
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ff8c00;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


.srch{
padding-top:15px;
padding-right:10px;

}



/*    brands      */
.brandtable{
    width:100%;
    
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:white;
}

/*footer*/
footer{
    
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide a link on your code

Comment: or inspect your element inside the footer tag by using devtools and look at the styles that were applied to the p tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of mistakes in your HTML, chrome somehow wraps your footer in center tag. You can check your HTML here and try to solve problems

https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Answer (score 1):

- Use table/td/tr tags only if you want to use it for table purpose. For other purpose you can use **HTML5** semantic/div tags with **CSS3** properties.
- Follow HTML5 semantic tag property w3school semantic : [w3school semantic tags](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)
- Try to use [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to check code quality.
- You can see, I took some of part from your code and convert into new style.  Solved **example** codepen.io/ganesh1172/footer-html5
- I hope you understand what I want to say. All the best  ✌️.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many problems with your markup. First thing is stop using `center` tag, that is outdated now, Use css instead to center the elements.

Your footer is wrapped inside the center tag ( very hard to find but if you see it with the chrome developer tool, you will find that ).

Try to learn modern Html5 and css3 syntax.
Happy learning.